# Difference in hashrate between two GPUs

Tags: gpu, performance, hashpower

I am a gamer who simply uses his rig to mine when idle. A year ago I was getting 0.5 Ghs using a [Radeon HD7970 3072MB 384bit OC Boost](http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/product_index.aspx?pid=1463&lid=1), then due to a technical issue I stopped mining for a few months and eventually replaced the Radeon with [GeForce GTX770 4096MB 256bit OC](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4629)...

On which I am currently getting a consistent 126Mhs.

What follows may be a dumb question, but did anything change (eg some network property), that would explain a much lower hashrate on a better card? Or is there something wrong with my setup?

I'm using: BTCGuild and BitMinter, GUIMiner, Win7

Comment: possible duplicate of [ATI OpenCL V.S. NVidia Cuda Cores](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10676/5406)

Comment: Should you be mining Bitcoin with a graphics card? You should look into other more profitable currencies to mine with those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer is that your card replacement caused the huge drop in hash-rate. Radeon cards are generally better for mining (faster and more efficient) compared to Nvidia. There is a nice chart that approximates hash rate per card here: https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison

You should really consider mining scrypt algorithm at either a profitability pool (I think BTCGuild has one now) that will mine the most profitable coin and convert it to BTC for you, for a small fee of course. This should increase your mining yield by 10fold or so!

You also might try Cudaminer instead of GUIMiner for nvidia cards. I have had better using cudaminer for nvidia gpus than both cg and bfgminer.

Answer (score -2):

you need to be using the cudaminer for Nvidia..

and now you should be using x11 to hash..

my GTX650ti went from 200kh scrypt to 1100kh x11 coins..

hit up a multipool like blackcoin.co/mining/

check out http://www.blackcoin.co/..

that card should scream.. especially with those specs.. maybe 2.4 to 3.4MH

I make 12 BC a day @ about .00024 Btc each a day..

http://cryptomining-blog.com/wp-content/files/ccminer-1.0-windows-new.zip

Nvidia is kicking ass right now..

Comment: Please use proper sentences and don't overuse abbreviations that uninitiated won't understand. The answer seems to be spending a bigger portion on a tangent than on the actual question. It would be beneficial if an explanation were given why the asker should be using Cudaminer.